# how to merge some columns data from different txt files in Python?

Tags: python, merge

I have some txt files, which need to extract certain columns out and store in one txt file.

a1.txt:

> 53,  42
>   54,  38
>   55,  37
>   57,  48

b1.txt:

> 45,  15,  30,  2
>  16,  59,  31,  4
>  87,  09,  32,  5
>   58,  16,  33,  3

what i need is 
c.txt (add the last column of b1.txt to the a1.txt):

> 53,  42, 2
>  54,  38, 4
>  55,  37, 5
>  57,  48, 3

the 4th column of `b.txt` should be added to the 5th column of `a.txt`. Then create a new file `c.txt`.
I try some code, but it did not work. cmd said `"TypeError: list indice must be integers, not srt"`. 
I have no idea how to merge the columns from different files together. Hopefully someone could help me to revise the code. Thank you so much!

```
def readf(filename):
    lines=file(filename).readlines()
    for i in lines:
        data=i.split()
    return data

fa=readf('a1.txt')
fb=readf('b1.txt')

lines=[]
for i in fa:
    s=fa[i]+fb[3]
    s+='\n'
    lines.append(s)

with open ('c.txt','w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
    f.close>
```

Comment: Try using pandas, the code shouldn't be more than 4 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following command you have passed a string as the index to a list :

```
for i in fa:
    s=fa[i]+fb[3]
```

*Note* that you are iterating over a file object!

but as a better way for such problems i suggest the `csv` module.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import csv
with open('a1.txt', 'rb') as csv1,open('b1.txt', 'rb') as csv2,open('c.txt', 'w') as out:
     spam1 = csv.reader(csv1, delimiter=',')
     spam2 = csv.reader(csv2, delimiter=',')
     last_column=list(izip_longest(*spam2))[-1]
     for i,j in  izip_longest(spam1,last_column):
        out.write(','.join([t.strip(';') for t in i])+','+j+'\n')
```

Here `last_column=list(izip_longest(*spam2))[-1]` will gave you the last column of `b1.txt` and `izip_longest(spam1,last_column)` will gave you the following list :

```
[(['53', ' 42;'], ' 2;'), (['54', ' 38;'], ' 4;'), (['55', ' 37;'], ' 5;'), (['57', ' 48; '], ' 3;')]
```

So you can strip the elements with `;` and write to file.

If `;` can be ignored you can change the last line to :

```
out.write(','.join(i)+','+j+'\n')
```

Comment: Thanks Kasra! Actually the ";" can be ignored (i made a mistake before). I try your code. But cmd said, line 9 has problem "invalid syntax" (actually it only has 8 lines, what's wrong with it?)  I try to edit your last line to {out.write(','.join(','+j+'\n')}  is it right?

Comment: yes, now it works! thank you. As i need to use this code in other .dat file. but in one file, the fist line is the title, how can i get the 5th column without the title? i tried, but it does not work.  ("can only join an iterable")<\b>  {last_column_d=list(izip_longest(*spam4))[4]
    n=1
    for i,j,m,n in izip_longest(spam1,last_column_2, last_column_3, last_column_4):
        out.write(','.join(i)+','+j+m+n+'\n')}

Comment: Welcome so if it works you can tell this to community by vote and accepting the answer ;) , and when you get the last column by `last_column=list(izip_longest(*spam2))[-1]` you can get ride of title that is the first element of the last column by a simple indexing `last_column=list(izip_longest(*spam2))[-1][1:]`

Comment: hi, Kasra, perhaps some more questions. is it possible to do calculate between two cloumns? I tried column_ratio=[]
    for x,y,z in izip_longest(column_ratio, column_1, column_2):
        column_ratio[x]=(float(column_1[y]))/(float(column_2[z])). but it showed"tuple indices must be integers, not str".  ps. i just added column_1=list (izip_longest(*spam1))[-1]. it was funny cmd said"can only join an iterable".

Comment: @YuzhangTu Hi, sorry i cant understand your code correctly, i suggest to ask it as a new question with a good explanation! ;)

Comment: thanks Kasra. I posted a new question. it would be grateful that you help me. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396046/calulation-between-two-column-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to split your text using `,` and `;` as parameters, you can use `re` to accomplish the job. Then is just a matter or writing all the attributes of the first file and the last attribute of the second file.

```
import re
with open("a.txt", 'r') as f:
    a1 = [re.findall(r"[\w']+", line) for line in f]
with open("b.txt", 'r') as b:
    b1 = [re.findall(r"[\w']+", line) for line in b]
with open("c.txt", 'w') as c:
    for x,y in zip(a1,b1):
        c.write("{},{}\n".format(",".join(x),y[-1]))
```

This creates file `c` which looks like

```
53,42,2 
54,38,4 
55,37,5 
57,48,3
```

Comment: Daniel, thank you so much! it works well. but when i try to program other .bat files. some problems:  in a.bat file, last column is 4.5E+28, and in b.bat file, what I need the column is like 3.9E+23. when i run the code, what i got is like 4,6E, 28, 23 (seems they regard "." as "," ). some improvement can be done?

Answer (score 2):

How about you use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
a1 = pd.read_csv('a1.txt', header= None ,escapechar=';')
b1 = pd.read_csv('b1.txt', header= None)

a1[2] = b1[3]

a1.to_csv('c.txt',index=False,header= False)
```

c.txt:

```
53, 42, 2;
54, 38, 4;
55, 37, 5;
57, 48, 3;
```

Comment: Thank you Ruk. Using pandas is really easy. But it seems it is difficult to install the pandas in windows-32bit. I try to install it, but no idea how to do it...would you give me some introduction?

Comment: You should try Anaconda. I comes pre-installed with a lot of libraries including pandas. Also try winPython, for that you can find pre-compiled binaries online so you don't have to compiled them yourself. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
def read_file(file_name):
    col_data = []
    with open(file_name) as data_file:
        for data in data_file.readlines():
            col1, col2, col3, col4 = data.split(",")
            col_data.append(col4[:-1])
    return col_data

numbers = read_file("b1.txt")

with open("a1.txt") as a_file:
    with open("new_file.txt", "w") as new_file:
        lines = a_file.readlines()
        for line in xrange(len(lines)):
            new_file.write(lines[line][:-1] + " ,"+numbers[line]+"\n")
```

Comment: Assuming that Number of rows in both the text file are exactly **same** I haven't tried this code on my machine, But I guess it should work on your machine, tell me if you face any errors?

Comment: thank you so much！ it works. just a problem: i run the code in other txt file. but in the ”new_file“, the last data miss the the last number from b1.txt.  it should be 8.8E+25, but only 8.8E+2, "5" is missing.  but when i run in .dat file, it works well!