# Calculation between two columns in Python?

Tags: python

When I tried to do some calculation between two columns (like division), I get an error: **`column_ratio[x]=(float(column1[y]))/(float(column2[z]))    TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str`**. Could someone help me to solve this problem?

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import csv
with open(r"C:\Users\a.txt", 'rb') as csv1,\
 open(r"C:\Users\b.txt", 'rb') as csv2, \
 open(r"C:\Users\c.txt", 'rb') as csv3, \
 open(r"C:\Users\out.txt", 'w') as out:

    spam1 = csv.reader(csv1, delimiter=',')
    spam2 = csv.reader(csv2, delimiter=',')
    spam3= csv.reader(csv3, delimiter=',')

    column1=list(izip_longest(*spam1))[-1]
    column2=list(izip_longest(*spam2))[-1]
    column3=list(izip_longest(*spam3))[-1]

    column_ratio=[]
    for x,y,z in izip_longest(column_ratio, column1, column2):
        column_ratio[x]=(float(column1[y]))/(float(column2[z]))

    for i,j,m,n,x in izip_longest(spam1,column1, column2, column3, column_ratio):
        out.write(','.join(i)+','+j+','+m+','+n+','+x+'\n')
```

Comment: Show us the full error with the stacktrace.

Comment: Put "print(x,y,z)" in the first for loop before the assignment

Comment: thanks! you mean like this: column_ratio=[]<br/>
    for x,y,z in izip_longest(column_ratio, column1, column2):<br/>print(x,y,z)<br/>
        column_ratio[x]=(float(column1[y]))/(float(column2[z]))

Answer (score 1):

When you parse with the CSV reader, it has no way of knowing that the data should be an integer, a float, a string, etc. All comma-delimited data is parsed as a string, and it's up to you to convert it to the right type. You'll need to coerce the string to an integer to use it as an index.

---

Take the following CSV:

```
Index One, Index Two, Index Three
0,1,2
```

When parsing it:

```
x, y, z = reader.next()  # ['0', '1', '2']
print my_tuple[x]  # TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
print my_tuple[int(x)]  # Expected result
```

Comment: thanks David. but i am sorry i still did not know how to edit the code.

Comment: This is a (generalized) explanation of your specific problem. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: when tried "print float(column1[1])/float(column2[1])", it works. but why for a loop it does not work?